# How to view complete CMD execution command, including arguments and flags?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, exe

In Visual Studio, how can the run command for a console application be viewed?

Imagine a complex C++ application with a lot of startup flags and arguments.

It runs fine from the "Debug -> Start Without Debugging" option from the menu.

I would like to run the executable within a Command Prompt window, without starting Visual Studio. I try and run the executable, without success, like so:

```
./myProgram.exe
```

How can the command that VS uses to start the application--with all flags and arguments--be viewed?

Comment: @downvote, the question is crystal-clear: how to view the command that VS is using to start an application.

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"?  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is running, [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows complete command line. If your app is short lived, [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) records what arguments were used to start it.